# How to return a list of objects with an extra field in Json (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm using ModelViewSet to generate a list of items by get_queryset. I want to return a json with the list of objects and an extra field (the sum total time of the DurationField).
Example:

```
{  
   "total_time":"00:10:00",
   "objects":[  
      {  
         "pk":1,
         "title":"Title",
         "duration": "00:05:00"
      },
      {  
         "pk":1,
         "title":"Title",
         "duration": "00:05:00"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I do this? Here's my code below.

ModelViewSet:

```
class ModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Model.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ModelSerializer
        permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

        def get_queryset(self):
            user = self.request.user
            list = Model.objects.filter(user=user)
            total_time = .. ## sum the duration of list of objects

            ## I want to return the list and total_time
            return list
```

serializers.py:

```
class ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
            user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), required=False, allow_null=True)
            project = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Project.objects.all(), required=False, allow_null=True)
            class Meta:
                model = Model

                fields = ('pk', 'title', 'user', 'project', 'duration')
```

urls:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'^', views.ModelViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to subclass the paginator (the default pagination class is `PageNumberPagination`) and tweaking the `get_paginated_response`.  This is wholly untested, but maybe something like this:

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class CustomPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):

    def get_paginated_response(self, data, total_time):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('count', self.page.paginator.count),
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('total_time', total_time),
            ('results', data)
        ]))


class ModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    pagination_class = CustomPageNumberPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        list = Model.objects.filter(user=user)

        self.total_time = .. ## sum the duration of list of objects

        return list

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return self.paginator.get_paginated_response(data, self.total_time)
```

Anyhow, hopefully this helps a bit.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @CaffeineFueled! But I do not know if this is the best practice! I did otherwise and I would appreciate, if you could kindly let me know your opinion about the code!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it! But I'm not sure if it's the best practice. If anyone has a better idea, please share!

```
class ModelJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):
    """
    Add "objects" and "total_time" in Json
    """
    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        data = {'objects': data, 'total_time': renderer_context['total_time']}
        return super(ModelJSONRenderer, self).render(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

ModelViewSet:

```
class ModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Model.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ModelSerializer
        permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    renderer_classes = (ModelJSONRenderer, )

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        list = Model.objects.filter(user=user)

        self.total_time = .. ## sum the duration of list of objects

        return list

    def get_renderer_context(self):
        """
        Returns a dict that is passed through to Renderer.render(),
        as the `renderer_context` keyword argument.
        """
        return {
            'view': self,
            'args': getattr(self, 'args', ()),
            'kwargs': getattr(self, 'kwargs', {}),
            'request': getattr(self, 'request', None),
            'total_time': self.total_time
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there's such a thing as a "best practice" in this scenario.  If you find something that works for you and it's not hideously complex and/or impossible to maintain, then I say run with it.  Sadly, I can't play around with your solution at the moment, but I think the concept looks sound.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks again @CaffeineFueled ;)